# regionByIntersectionWithRegion: not working in Sprite Kit

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sprite-kit

I'm trying to use the SpriteKit SKRegion class to compute intersection, difference, union of closed CGPaths, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is a simple example that I would expect to work but nothing is rendered here.

```
CGPathRef a = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100), NULL);
CGPathRef b = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(50, 0, 100, 100), NULL);
SKRegion *ra = [[SKRegion alloc] initWithPath:a];
SKRegion *rb = [[SKRegion alloc] initWithPath:b];
SKRegion *rc = [ra regionByIntersectionWithRegion:rb];
CGPathRef c = [rc path];
CGContextRef context = (CGContextRef)[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
CGContextAddPath(context, c);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

Rendering `a` and `b` works, but nothing appears for `c` although these circles do overlap.

Other scenarios fail to work as well, such as using basic rectangles for a and b, or even using different SKRegion constructors that don't operate on paths.

Any ideas?

Comment: I couldn't get the simplest case to work in Swift or Obj-C. I suspect it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to render ra.path, you need to use very high values to get the same size for the circles. I used 3000 instead of 100 and that way you could see the circles.

For some reason rc is nil so, it must be a bug or a beta feature.

Answer (score -1):

CGContext doesn't render to a SKView. You need to use SKNode objects, most likely SKShapeNode if you want to see the paths being drawn to the screen.

Comment: I'm not rendering into an SKView. I was only using the SKRegion part of Sprite Kit, specifically for this intersection / union / difference code.

Comment: And as I mentioned, I can render CGPathRefs `a` and `b` just fine.